# reducing JavaScript lib file size coding techniques

Tags: javascript, coding-style, size

I'm working on a JavaScript lib which has forked from an earlier internal project. Over time its increased in file size and I'm now keen to reduce it. I'm just wondering if any one has run into any techniques/coding styles for writing more efficient JavaScript ? The performance is pretty okay its now just the file size that is the problem.

We already minify the lib.

Thanks as always SO

Comment: what size files are you lokking at, once minified?

Comment: We've increased about 50% in size from our orig forked lib but definitely not added that level of extra functionality. I'm kinda after something like a good style guide.

Comment: Good style is  very much dependent on goals, readable or compact. Refactoring common actions to methods is one way to reduce footprint but to give more examples some code examples would help.

Answer (score 0):

Which compressor are you using ? have you investigate caching ?

Comment: google closure compiler - caching not in my scope need to improve by writing better/more line efficient code.